# How to perform grouped-by aggregations on array of objects in fp-ts?

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I'm trying to analyze data given as an array of nested objects. I want to use *fp-ts* ecosystem, and I'm trying to figure out how I could combine a *grouped-by* calculation with any pre-defined function (such as, calculating average, median, mode, sum, standard deviation, etc.).

### Example

I have an array of objects, where each object holds data about a different student. Here we have 3 students.

```js
const studentsGrades = [
  {
    name: 'john',
    age: 21,
    classes: {
      history: {
        grade: 89,
        semester: 'spring',
        category: 'humanities',
      },
      math: {
        grade: 95,
        semester: 'all_year',
        category: 'quantitative',
      },
      physics: {
        grade: 81,
        semester: 'fall',
        category: 'quantitative',
      },
      literature: {
        grade: 77,
        semester: 'spring',
        category: 'humanities',
      },
    },
  },

  {
    name: 'amanda',
    age: 20,
    classes: {
      history: {
        grade: 95,
        semester: 'spring',
        category: 'humanities',
      },
      math: {
        grade: 99,
        semester: 'all_year',
        category: 'quantitative',
      },
      physics: {
        grade: 89,
        semester: 'fall',
        category: 'quantitative',
      },
      literature: {
        grade: 65,
        semester: 'spring',
        category: 'humanities',
      },
    },
  },

  {
    name: 'rachel',
    age: 19,
    classes: {
      history: {
        grade: 80,
        semester: 'spring',
        category: 'humanities',
      },
      math: {
        grade: 90,
        semester: 'all_year',
        category: 'quantitative',
      },
      physics: {
        grade: 100,
        semester: 'fall',
        category: 'quantitative',
      },
      literature: {
        grade: 88,
        semester: 'spring',
        category: 'humanities',
      },
    },
  },
];
```

I want to perform different calculations. For example, what is the *average* grade for physics? What is the *median* grade for literature? What is the *standard deviation* in grades of humanities classes?

---

One way for me to reason about it, is to separately define independent functions that do those calculation on arrays. For example:

***average***

```js
const calcMean = (arr: number[]): number => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, v, i, a) => acc + v / a.length, 0); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/62372003/6105259
};
```

***median***

```js
const calcMedian = (arr: number[]): number => {
  if (!arr.length) return undefined;
  const s = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const mid = Math.floor(s.length / 2);
  return s.length % 2 === 0 ? ((s[mid - 1] + s[mid]) / 2) : s[mid];
}; // https://stackoverflow.com/a/70806192/6105259
```

***standard deviation***

```js
const calcStandardDeviation = (arr: number[]): number => {
  const mean = calcMean(arr);
  const variance = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + (n - mean) ** 2, 0) / (arr.length - 1);
  return Math.sqrt(variance);
}; // https://stackoverflow.com/a/68258974/6105259
```

Alright but now what? How can I apply any function of interest (i.e., either `calcMean()`, `calcMedian()`, or `calcStandardDeviation()`) on `studentsGrades` to answer my analysis questions by grouping by the relevant key?

Comment: In addition to your calculation functions, you'll need some functions to grab the relevant data from your data structure. I'm imagining something like `getClassResults("physics", studentsGrades)` and `getCategoryResults("humanities", studentsGrades)`. Then you can combine these "accessor" type functions with your calculation functions to get the final results you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using fp-ts, you should use `Option` instead of returning `undefined` for `calcMedian`. It's also good to type parameters as taking readonly arrays when they don't modify the array:

```ts
import * as O from 'fp-ts/Option';

const calcMean = (arr: readonly number[]): number => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, v) => acc + v, 0) / arr.length;
};

const calcMedian = (arr: readonly number[]): O.Option<number> => {
  if (!arr.length) return O.none;
  const sorted = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const mid = Math.trunc(sorted.length / 2);
  return O.some(
    sorted.length % 2 === 0
      ? (sorted[mid - 1]! + sorted[mid]!) / 2
      : sorted[mid]!
  );
};

const calcStandardDeviation = (arr: readonly number[]): number => {
  const mean = calcMean(arr);
  const variance = arr.reduce((s, n) => s + (n - mean) ** 2, 0) / (arr.length - 1);
  return Math.sqrt(variance);
};
```

For getting the subjects data:

```ts
import * as RA from 'fp-ts/ReadonlyArray';
import * as O from 'fp-ts/Option';
import {pipe} from 'function';

const gradesByClass = (className: string): readonly number[] =>
  pipe(
    studentsGrades,
    RA.filterMap(({classes}) => O.fromNullable(classes[className]?.grade))
  );

const gradesByCategory = (categoryName: string): readonly number[] =>
  pipe(
    studentsGrades,
    RA.chain(({classes}) => Object.values(classes)),
    RA.filterMap(({category, grade}) => category === categoryName ? O.some(grade) : O.none)
  );
```

- [`RA.chain`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/ReadonlyArray.ts.html#chain)
- [`RA.filterMap`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/ReadonlyArray.ts.html#filtermap)
- [`O.fromNullable`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Option.ts.html#fromnullable)

Then you can use these functions like this:

```ts
calcMean(gradesByClass('physics'))
calcMedian(gradesByClass('literature'))
calcStandardDeviation(gradesByCategory('humanities'))
```